# How can I get all the parent element by providing child element ID in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, hierarchical-data

My Oracle table looks like this

```
 ID     | ParentID   
 -----------------
 1      |        0  
 2      |        1  
 3      |        2  
 4      |        3  
 5      |        3
```

If I know only ID and need to get all parent elements in oracle, what is the query I need to use?

ex:- If I pass 5, need to get 5 > 3 > 2 > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a recursive CTE

```
WITH cte (id, parentid, p) 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                parentid, 
                To_char(id) AS p 
         FROM   t 
         WHERE  id = :p_id --enter 5
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t.id, 
                t.parentid, 
                c.p 
                || '>' 
                || t.id AS p 
         FROM   t 
                JOIN cte c 
                  ON ( c.parentid = t.id )) 
SELECT p 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  parentid = 0 --Highest parent.
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44fc8/18)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (id, parent) as
  2    (select 1, 0 from dual union
  3     select 2, 1 from dual union
  4     select 3, 2 from dual union
  5     select 4, 3 from dual union
  6     select 5, 3 from dual
  7    )
  8  select listagg(id, '->') within group (order by level) result
  9  from test
 10  start with id = &par_id
 11  connect by prior parent = id;
Enter value for par_id: 5

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
5->3->2->1

SQL>
```